# How not to render objects in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have too many objects in my game and they are effecting badly on performance of the game. but since there are like two-five percent of them visible for a player at a time (got a pretty big game area) is there a way to not render the object that player can't see at a time? any other approach to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only dynamic tilemap layers in phaser3 have culling support :(